# CPLEX+JAVA memory issues, retain last found solution

Tags: java, memory, cplex

I have the following problem: My CPLEX model runs into an out-of-memory-error (1001). This is to be expected, but I would like to retain the last solution (incumbent and gap, as well as all variable values).

```
try {
    if (cplex.solve()) {
         //feasible and ran without memory issues
    } else {
         //infeasible
     }
} catch (IloException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     //memory issues end up in here
}​
```

The problem is that I "end up" in the catch part, where I can no longer retain any variable values, objective function values etc. 
Is there a work-around to help me get the last found solution?
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
cplex.solve()
```

in the try you could do a loop with

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex.Param.MIP.Limits.Solutions, 1);
cplex.solve();
```

and then you ll get  solutions one by one. If you crash in the last one, you ll be able to have the previous one.

Comment: if someone else tries to implement this solution: works great, I went for a combination of time limit and "if not yet optimal"
`while (System.nanoTime() - starttime < 7200000000000L && !status.equals("Optimal")) {`
where status has been set using cplex.getStatus().toString()

Comment: one more issue, that might also affect others: if the starting solution is optimal, the gap is very high (99.x%) rather than 0. I found that this can be circumvented by just making sure to iterate once more (I did that by having a variable statusPrev that reached Optimal one iteration after status)

Comment: There are other (IMO better) ways to do this: a) you can use a MIPInfoCallback. This is invoked frequently and you can capture feasible solutions from there. b) You can use a generic global progress callback. That also allows to capture solutions when they are found. c) You can use parameter `CPX_PARAM_INTSOLFILEPREFIX` which writes solutions to disk as they are found. d) Even with out of memory you will almost always be able to call `cplex.getValues()` even in the `catch` block. e) Use a node file on disk to actually avoid the out of memory completely.